# How to stop a loop at a number not have it go that number of times in C

Tags: c, math

I was trying to make a code that shows you the multiples of any given number, but it's going over the numbers. I'm pretty sure I'm overthinking it, but I need help. Here's the code I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int c=0;    
int b= 0;
int a= 0;
//insert n
printf("Please enter a number:");
scanf("%d",&a);
//Pick the multiple
printf("Do you want to count in multiples of 2, 3, or 5:");
scanf ("%d",&b);

for(b=0; b=a; b++)
{
    c=a*b;
 printf("\n%d",c);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loop `for(b=0; b=a; b++)` looks wrong.  `b=a` is an assignment.  Did you want it to be a comparison?

Comment: Your loop condition is wrong. You need to read some good books about programming my friend.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &b);` inputs to `b` which is immediately overwritten as the loop iterator `b`.

Comment: Aside: it is more usual to write `printf("\n%d", c);` as `printf("%d\n", c);` with the newline *last*.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. If the input is `6` and `3`, what should the output be?

Comment: When the code is corrected, there is still no clear way to know when to stop the iteration, because the program does not define it and the limit is not requested.

Comment: `b=a` is probably a typo

Comment: @Haley Hilbert,  Save time.  Enable all warnings and get quick results like "warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]    for (b = 0; b = a; b++) {" indicting something amiss with `for(b=0; b=a; b++)`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for(b=0; b=a; b++)
> {
>     c=a*b;
>     printf("\n%d",c);
> }
> ```

As has been pointed out in comments, the loop condition is wrong. `b=a` assigns the value of `a` to `b`, which is certainly not what you want. You were probably thinking `b==a`, but that'd be incorrect also. A `for` loop continues executing while the condition is *true*, so you want a condition that's true for b==0,1,2,3...a. In other words, you want `<=`, i.e.:

```
for(b=0; b<=a; b++)
{
    c=a*b;
    printf("\n%d",c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Hii, i think you nedd this!
>
> This is my full program below

```
#include<stdio.h>

int getMultiplication(int a, int b) {
    return a*b;
}

int main() {
    int c = 0;    
    int b = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Please enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    printf("Do you want to count in multiples of 2, 3, or 5:");
    scanf ("%d",&b);

    // For Multiplication
    c = getMultiplication(a, b);
    printf("Multiplication Is :- %d\n",c);

    // For Multiplies from1 1 to b with a
    for(i=1; i<=b; i++) {
        c = getMultiplication(a, i);
        printf("%d * %d = %d\n", a, i, c);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

> if you want to multiplies that **a and b** number so you can use this

```
// For Multiplication
c = getMultiplication(a, b);
printf("Multiplication Is :- %d\n",c);
```

> But if you want to excute multiplication of **a** with **1 to till b** so you can use this

```
// For Multiplies from1 1 to b with a
for(i=1; i<=b; i++) {
    c = getMultiplication(a, i);
    printf("%d * %d = %d\n", a, i, c);
}
```

> For loop working machanism below
> if you like this then aprricate you

[image]